# Could not convert string to DateTime and The field is required in NewtonSoftJson

Tags: c#, .net-core

I try pass data below.

```
{
  "Name": "Test",
  "Date": "1631149200826"
}
```

My Class as below:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int qty { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Everything works fine when using .NET Framework.

But I got 2 error when using .NET Core 3.1 and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson 3.1.8.

error1：Could not convert string to DateTime: 1631149200826. Path 'data.Date'

error2：The Item field is required.

I know it could solve error2 if I add some "ignore property" on my class.

But I wonder if there are other solution?

For example, add some options on controller?

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson().AddJsonOptions();
```

Comment: What exactly is `1631149200826`? Is it ticks? Is it milliseconds since Unix epoch? Is it something else entirely? How do you expect .NET to know?

Comment: That's not a DateTime. The [standard date format in JSON](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7493#section-4.3) is ISO8601. There's no good reason to use a custom format, definitely not one that is unclear even to humans. Is that seconds? Milliseconds? Ticks? Since when? What is the offset?

Comment: `Everything works fine when using .NET Framework.` no it doesn't, unless you created a custom converter. JSON.NET *never* parsed raw numbers as dates. It uses the standard format as well. 10 years ago, when there was no accepted standard, it used `"\/Date(1198908717056)\/"` which was used by Microsoft in the early AJAX days. Since 2012 though it uses proper ISO8601 dates

Answer (score 1):

Supposing the `Date` value is the number of milliseconds since the start of epoch, you could do something similar to this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int qty { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Date")]
    public long DateAsMilliseconds { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public DateTime Date => TimeUtils.UnixMillisecondsToDateTime(DateAsMilliseconds);
}

public class TimeUtils
{
    public static DateTime UnixMillisecondsToDateTime(double unixTimeStamp)
    {
        DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        dateTime = dateTime.AddMilliseconds(unixTimeStamp).ToLocalTime();
        return dateTime;
    }
}
```

Update: as suggested in the comments a far better idea would be to use the standard date format ISO8601.

Comment: A far better idea would be to use the standard date format, ISO8601

Comment: You are right. My answer is for case the Date property cannot be changed to ISO format maybe for some legacy reason.

Comment: It would be an extremely weird reason, as for the last 10 years JSON.NET uses ISO8601. It never used raw milliseconds. JSON.NET would need a custom type converter to handle the OP's format. It's possible to create type converters for System.Text.JSON as well but ....

Answer (score 0):

The [standard date format in JSON](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7493#section-4.3) is ISO8601, ie `2021-09-09T10:52:01+00:00` or `2021-09-09T10:52:01Z`. JSON.NET never parsed raw numbers as dates. As [the docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm) explain:

> The default format used by Json.NET is the ISO 8601 standard: "2012-03-19T07:22Z".
>
> Prior to Json.NET 4.5 dates were written using the Microsoft format: "/Date(1198908717056)/". If you want to use this format, or you want to maintain compatibility with Microsoft JSON serializers or older versions of Json.NET, then change the DateFormatHandling setting to MicrosoftDateFormat.

The only way `"1631149200826"` can be converted to a `DateTime` is through a custom type converter.

The **correct** solution would be to switch to the standard date format.

If you want to keep using JSON.NET, you'll have to add the custom type converter that handled `"1631149200826"`.

It's possible to create a [custom DateTime converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#sample-basic-converter) for System.Text.Json as well. It's used in a similar way as JSON.NET custom converters, either through serializer options or though JSON attibutes.

In this case, the converter could be:

```
public class DateTimeMilliJsonConverter : JsonConverter<DateTime>
{
    public override DateTime Read(
        ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
        Type typeToConvert,
        JsonSerializerOptions options) 
    {
        long millis=long.Parse(reader.GetString());
        return DateTime.UnixEpoch.AddMilliseconds(millis);
    }

    public override void Write(
        Utf8JsonWriter writer,
        DateTime dateTimeValue,
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        long millis=(long)dateTimeValue.Subtract(DateTime.UnixEpoch).TotalMilliseconds;
        writer.WriteStringValue(millis.ToString());
    }
}
```

The converter can be applied to a property through the `JsonConverter` attribute

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int qty { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(DateTimeOffsetJsonConverter))]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```